# Custom domain for API Gateway using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to define a custom domain (sub domain actually) for an API Gateway using CloudFormation. According to all the documentation I've been able to find the following should work but when I deploy it I get `Invalid domain name identifier specified` for the `BasePathMapping`

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file packaged-prompt.yaml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --stack-name prompt-stack
```

prompt.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:

  ...

  Certificate:
    Type: 'AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate'
    Properties:
      DomainName: example.mydomain.com

  DomainName:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName'
    Properties:
      CertificateArn: !Ref Certificate
      DomainName: example.mydomain.com

  Mapping:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping'
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName
      RestApiId: !Ref Api

  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        paths:

          ....
```

Comment: Do you get the error when you deploy the stack in CloudFormation, or when you deploy the API in API Gateway? Do you get the same result if you specify the stage in the BasePathMapping?

Comment: When I deploy in CloudFormation. When I set the stage the CloudFormation hangs on `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. It's been over an hour since the last event.

Comment: It generally takes about 40 minutes for a Domain Name with EDGE endpointConfigurationType.
Can you try using REGIONAL endpointConfigurationType (which should be take only a few seconds to create). Its possible to do this from cfn https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html#cfn-apigateway-domainname-endpointconfiguration ?

Comment: Also, as you're creating a certificate in this stack, it will hang until you've verified it. The owner of the domain for which you are registering the certificate will [receive an email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-email.html) asking for verification. Another way is to use [DNS verification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html). If you actually are trying to register `mydomain.com`, unless you own it and can verify it, the stack will eventually fail. Interested to know what the eventual failure message was.

Comment: Are you sure your input domain name is in a valid format and doesn't contain any characters? For example, are you accidentally entering HTTP or domaincom forgetting a dot?

Answer (score 0):

The properties in your BasePathMapping is missing

```
BasePath: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the DomainName and the Api Gateway where not in the same region

Answer (score -1):

It may not be the case, but I had the same problem as I was using uppercase letters in my domain-name, which must be avoided. See [BaseUrl Mapping in AWS with inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223469/baseurl-mapping-in-aws-with-inconsistencies)