# BaseUrl Mapping in AWS with inconsistencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating custom domain for api gateway using yaml. Here is my sample yaml.

```
TestAppApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref ApiStageName
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      TracingEnabled: TRUE
      MethodSettings:
        - LoggingLevel: INFO
          ResourcePath: "/*" # allows for logging on any resource
          HttpMethod: "*" # allows for logging on any method
          DataTraceEnabled: TRUE
      
  DomainName:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Properties:
      RegionalCertificateArn: !Ref Certificate
      DomainName: !Ref ApiDomain
      SecurityPolicy: TLS_1_2
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      
  UrlMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    DependsOn:
      - TestAppApiStage
      - DomainName
    Properties:
      DomainName:
        !Ref ApiDomain
      RestApiId:
        Ref: TestAppApi
      Stage: !Ref ApiStageName
  
  Domain:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    DependsOn:
      - TestAppApi
      - UrlMapping
      - DomainName
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref ApiDomainHostedZoneId
      RecordSets:
        - Name: !Ref ApiDomain 
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            DNSName: !GetAtt DomainName.RegionalDomainName
            HostedZoneId: !GetAtt DomainName.RegionalHostedZoneId
```

I am passing ApiDomain as parameter and it works as expected when my ApiDomain is 'dev.test.com.au' where test.com.au is my registered domain. But if I change my ApiDomain to something like 'dev-$env:USERNAME.test.com.au' and then I get the following error.

**Invalid domain name identifier specified(Service:AmazonApiGateway;Status Code: 404;
Error Code: NotFoundException;Request ID: fbf8ce40-cce0-4a0f-9714-c649d35a3ee4; Proxy: null)**

Apparently this error has something to do with the dependency issue according to this thread https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/192# but it works with one name but not the other. And anyways I have added all the dependencies and still invalid domain name identifier error.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Don't have capital letters in your domain name people. My ApiDomain parameter has capital letters. Domain name creation automatically converts it to lower letters. But baseurlmapping is left to find ApiDomain with capital letter and hence the issue. Needed to read documentation more clearly but anyhow posting it here in case somebody experiences this silly issue.